# User's TimeZone preference in a website and storing DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, .net-core

I created a facility in a web site so that every user can set his TimeZone preference, and this preference is saved in DB as the total offset minutes for that city. for example +60 or -60 (OffsetMinutes).
Now I want to store user's DateTime.Now (For a Blog Post he send) like this:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(OffsetMinutes);
```

Is this correct and Okay?

Comment: Correct for what? The timestamps on your data should always be set by the server and should always be saved as UTC. Displaying those timestamps should be the job of the frontend. But even then, please don't write it all yourself, .NET already has classes to handle this.

Comment: @nvoigt Read Jon Skeet's [Storing Utc Is Not A Silver Bullet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/#:~:text=Convert%20to%20UTC%20as%20soon,zone%20issue%20again%2C%20they%20say.)

Comment: @ZoharPeled That is an interesting read (I am in the EU myself), but I think in this case, it's not about dates in the far future but just about timestamps that are immediate past. So yes, it's not a silver bullet, but it's "good enough" and surely better than the proposed solution to somehow calculate offsets themselves.

Comment: I think the best way as was said, Is to store dates as UTC, Then with whatever way that is prefered, Bring that date to Preferenced time zone when displaying Blog posts.